# Error while intergrating Terraform with github

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I am trying to integrate `terraform` on my mac to `github`. I have taken token from github and used in the below code, but getting the below error, what could be an issue,

```
 Error: GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 Bad credentials []
 
   with provider["registry.terraform.io/integrations/github"],
   on github.tf line 10, in provider "github":
   10: provider "github" {
```

Below is the code for reference,

```
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        github = {
          source  = "integrations/github"
          version = "~> 4.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "github" {
      token = "9f07bd456019eebe4b0341f52ad3f5ad434a8c58"
    }
    
    resource "github_repository" "terraform" {
      name        = "Terraform"
      description = "Test for terraform intergration"
    
      visibility = "private"
    
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Terraform on your Github repository using Github Actions? (if yes, I suggest to take a look on the marketplace, where many automations using Terraform have already been created to make it easier to manage the tool: https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=terraform+)

Comment: no, i am trying to create repo in github using terraform by running code from my PC. for that i need to integrate terraform with github, so it's failing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if there is something wrong with your github token.

To make sure the token is good, please create a new token at https://github.com/settings/tokens with permissions to "repo" (and "delete_repo" if you want to be able to delete it also from terraform) and update the new token into your terraform code.

If you delete the token from github, it won't work on your terraform code either, so also do not delete the token on github as long as you intend to continue using the token on terraform.